# Most useful Asp.net MVC 3 Library every programmer shoud have?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I was was wondering that which are the most useful, easy to integrate, easy to code and powerful libraries available in the market (Free, Paid) that every MVC programmer should use to achieve the ultimate goal "Write Less, DO More"

I am currently using Auto-Mapper, Structure-Map, Jquery.

Please list yours so that every beginner like me can benefits from your answer.

Every piece of your answers would be appreciated and it deserve the vote up.

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/): The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery
```

*Wouldn't forgive myself this not being first one*

Following the write less do more principle, I could add

- [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) lots of community html helpers
- [Cassette](https://github.com/andrewdavey/cassette) (aka Knapsack) - script and stylesheet reference helper library(with script dependency inspection, version control, single place output(in master file), minification, etc)
- [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) - when it comes to defining validation. Clear, fluent code with separate, reusable, configurable validators. Excellent support of asp.net mvc3

Comment: of course.. how can i forgot to mention that...thanks...anything else u have in your mind...

Answer (score 4):

This is a very subjective question, however Nuget keeps a track of packages downloaded here: http://stats.nuget.org/#downloads if you are just looking for popularity stats.

Comment: oh .. i dint think about that....thanks for sharing...

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the UI abstraction that a library is putting on ASP.NET MVC but **TelerikMvcExtensions** fits your description :

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/TelerikMvcExtensions

However, *IMO*, if you like to have more **Write Less, DO More** approach, use **ASP.NET Web Forms**. Sometimes you don't need to write anything, just clicking and you are done. (which I don't like)

Comment: aahh !! even i dontlike the webforms anymore.. thanks for the link though...

Answer (score 1):

I prefer powerful MVC Extensions from DevExpress vendor.

Product Page:

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/MVC/

Demo Page:

http://mvc.devexpress.com/

Download Page:

https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/Downloads/#Trials

Answer (score 1):

Sitemaps can be a bit tricky in MVC so take a look at MVCSitemapProvider

http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com

ELMAH takes a lot of effort out of your error handling and logging

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

It's got a bit of a learning curve but KnockOutJS can fit quite well with MVC

http://knockoutjs.com

And not quite "write less" but definitely "do more" take a look at EF Code First

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EFCodeFirst/1.1

Comment: great list of packages ....thx